# How to install PyQt4-phonon (python3 version) on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt4

I have installed pyqt4 on ubuntu. Now my project requires pyqt4-phonon module. I have tried this way below which I got from the Internet:

```
sudo apt-get install Python-qt4-phonon
```

but I still cannot use phonon module in python3. While the module is available in python2. It seems to show that I've installed pyqt4-phonon of python2 version.

So, what should I do if I want to install pyqt4-phonon of python3 version?

Comment: Just want to point out that if you're looking to install this on Python 2.7 / ubuntu there's a small typo in the terminal command, it should read: `sudo apt-get install Python-qt4.phonon`

Comment: But I find `sudo apt-get install Python-qt4-phonon` work on my Ubuntu. Maybe they are equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install the Python 3 bindings for Qt4 Phonon, run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4.phonon
```